# echoing in shell -n doesn't get printed the right thing

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I know that this is some kind of special character issue but I do not know how to solve it.

I type in console

```
echo "-n"
```

and nothing get printed :(

I also tried with

```
echo -e "-n"
```

to execute the special characters (the one escaped from sequence) but again nothing happend

how can I print "-n" ?

Comment: Impressive that I have never run across this problem.  Good one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
aix@aix:~$ echo -e '\x2dn'
-n
```

It escapes the `-` as `\x2d`.

A more verbose way is to print the two characters separately:

```
aix@aix:~$ echo -n -; echo n
-n
```

Here, the `-n` instructs the first `echo` to not print a newline; it is not related to the `-n` being printed. :)

Comment: The POSIX definition of echo doesn't guarantee this to work. In fact, any implementation where `echo -e` doesn't print `-e` on its output is violating the standard, by which `-n` is the only allowable option [and, while allowable, not well-defined: `echo -n` simply makes output undefined, thus no longer required to conform to any particular specification].

Comment: In bash, `shopt -s xpg_echo` makes its `echo` standards-compliant when `set -o posix` is also enabled, meaning the `echo -e` hack given here will no longer work.

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
printf "%s\n" -n
```

or

```
printf "%s\n" '-n'
```

Comment: Yes, `printf` is more powerful and consistent than `echo`.